# does this scriptline need escaping

Tags: bash, alfred

Very simple question, I need to know if the "query" parameter from Alfred still works
My guess is, it wil not.

If so, how do you properly escape?

```
mysql -u [root] -p[foo] -e "create database [{query}];"
```

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself with `echo "[{query}]" > /tmp/out`?

Comment: Can you put it in an answer, because I saw that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it out yourself:

- use a command like `echo "[{query}]" > /tmp/out`
- execute the Alfred action
- open Terminal and run `cat /tmp/out` to see the result